# Retrive radio button and checkbox value form database using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i want to get value from database using jquery. i perform different operation but i have not success to get the value of Radio button and Checkbox value. Why value is not retrieved from database not showing?

**HTML**

```
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Active<span class="vd_red"></span></label>
             <div id="Active-input-wrapper" class="controls col-sm-6">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="isactive" data-rel="switch" id="chkactive">
             </div>
             <br /><br /><br />
             <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Duty Manager<span class="vd_red"></span></label>
             <div id="DutyManager-input-wrapper" class="controls col-sm-6">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="manager" data-rel="switch" id="chkdutymanager">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    
     <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-xl-12">
             <label class="control-label col-sm-2">User Type <span class="vd_red">*</span></label>
             <div id="email-input-wrapper" class="controls col-xl-8">
                 <div class="vd_radio radio-success">
                     <input type="radio" checked value="A" id="optionsRadios3" name="usertype">
                     <label for="optionsRadios3">Admin</label>
                     <input type="radio" value="U" name="usertype" id="optionsRadios4">
                     <label for="optionsRadios4">User</label>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

**Jquery Function**

```
function secuserID(UserId) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/GetUser/" + UserId,
            typr: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {

                $('#txtuserid').val(result.User_Id);
                $('#textUsername').val(result.User_name);
                $('#txtuserlogin').val(result.User_Login);
                $('#txtpassword').val(result.User_password);

                 $("input[name='usertype']:checked").val(result.User_Type); //not working

           
                $("#cmbGroupid").val(result.Group_Id);

                //$('#chkactive').prop('checked').val(result.Active); not working

                $('#chkactive').val(result.Active); //not working


                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $('#btnUpdate').show();
                $('#btnAdd').hide();
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Result

[image: Screenshort]

Answer (score 0):

The value of `result.User_Type` and `result.Active` must be either true or false. The jQuery version >= 1.6 supports the prop method. One thing I noticed that you are using the same name `usertype` for multiple radio buttons, so only one radio button will be checked.

```
$("input[name='usertype']:checked").each(function () {
    $(this).prop("checked", result.User_Type);
});

$("#chkactive").prop("checked", result.Active);
```